# Linux Installation - Boot Manager Not Finding CD/USB

Tags: ubuntu, installation, boot-manager

I have an Acer Aspire laptop with an intel I5 processor. I'm trying to install ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. My problem is my boot manager is NOT finding my external hard drive nor the dvd I made with the ubuntu ISO.
I've done everything I can think of including re-prioritizing the boot order so the Windows boot manager is the lowest priority. I've turned off fast boot and secure boot, restarted my laptop and the boot manager still only lists the option to boot windows.

Any ideas?
Thanks, Alex

Answer (score -1):

*having less than 50 reps, I can't make comments*

Go Back to BIOS ahead to the boot settings and select CMS or Legacy boot mode instead of UEFI boot mode.

Comment: I will give it a shot when i get home, thanks for the tip!

Comment: This is a comment.  If you would like to leave comments.  Please submit excellent complete and detailed answers in the future.  Comments posted as answers will just end up you being unable to submit answers in the future.  I am highly suspicious of anyone that does this and report all unusual behavior.

Comment: I am suspicious of people who leave comments badgering others trying to help, especially when they don't seem to know how periods work.

Comment: So I switched to BIOS Legacy Mode and I was able to find my external hard drive. Unfortunately when I chose this, it takes me to a grey screen with a flashing underscore that does nothing. I tried to be patient and after 5 minutes I stopped whatever process may have been happening. Looking at the external, its' light flashes like it's doing something but like I said, after 5 minutes - nothing. Any other ideas?